# Permission denied: .composer/vendor/bin

Tags: laravel

Recently, the way of installing Laravel's command has changed. You can see this here: http://laravel.com/docs/installation#install-laravel

After execute `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`

I'm receiving this error

`permission denied: .composer/vendor/bin`

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: are you running cmd as admin?

Comment: Yes, I am. Thank you Logan

Comment: I fixed this using a link to ´.composer/vendor/bin´ with this code:
`sudo ln -s ~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel /usr/local/bin/laravel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use with the PATH variable add this in to your bash_profile

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Then you can source your bash_profile to use laravel commands.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```